# Привязать Enum к DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, список

Есть `BindingList<ActionEnum>`, его я хочу использовать в качестве `DataSource` в DataGridView.

`ActionEnum` это перечисления

Хочу привязать к этим свойствам:

```
//Сюда хочу присвоить номер элемента перечисления
    dgvPermitionActions.Columns["Action_id"].DataPropertyName
//Сюда хочу присвоить как он называется
    dgvPermitionActions.Columns["ActionName"].DataPropertyName
```

Можно ли его привязать таким образом, что бы в итоге у меня получилось 2 колонки:
Порядковый номер|Название

Comment: А что представляет собой `ActionEnum`?

Comment: Обычное перечисление из N-ого кол-ва элементов.

Comment: Тогда добавьте это в вопрос, это не очевидно. Например, я подумал про это: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. И следующий вопрос — что означают `Action_id` и `ActionName`? Эти строки важны? И что такое `dgvPermitionActions`, вы нигде не говорите об этом, мы должны догадаться?

Comment: Это 2 атрибута DataGridView. В Action_id я хочу затолкать порядковый номер перечисления, а в ActionName имя элемента.

Comment: Ага, теперь понятно. (Может, добавите это в вопрос?)

Comment: Вопрос поправил.

Comment: Пробовал, не выходит :-) (Но я полный профан в WinForms.)